# Do I need to create a custom control?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, custom-controls

I want to adjust the corner radius on my buttons.  I can do this by creating a separate style resource and setting the corner radius of a border in the template.  However, I have to create a separate style for every variation.

What I want is an actual CornerRadius property that I can set for each button and not have to create another style every time I want a different corner radius.

Is my only solution here to create a custom control?

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote. This is an interesting question.

Comment: +1 too. WTF the downvote? This is really interesting, and provides a nice opportunity for an attached property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some playing around I have concluded the easiest way to do this is bind to an attached property of type ConerRadius.

### In the template you bind the Corner Radius like this:

```
<Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Corner.Radii}"
```

### You use it like this:

```
<Button Corner.Radii="10"
```

or even like this:

```
<Button Corner.Radii="2, 10, 10, 2"
```

### Examples:

[image]

Full code follows:

### Attached property class:

```
public static class Corner
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiiProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "Radii",
      typeof(CornerRadius),
      typeof(UIElement), null);

    public static void SetRadii(UIElement element, CornerRadius value)
    {
        element.SetValue(RadiiProperty, value);
    }

    public static CornerRadius GetRadii(UIElement element)
    {
        return (CornerRadius)element.GetValue(RadiiProperty);
    }
}
```

### Sample page using it:

Note: the button template is included inline in full for this example

```
<UserControl x:Class="CornerBehaviorTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:CornerBehaviorTest="clr-namespace:CornerBehaviorTest" mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#D8FFFFFF"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#8CFFFFFF"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#3FFFFFFF"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".55"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerBehaviorTest:Corner.Radii}" Background="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Margin="1">
                                    <Border Opacity="0"  x:Name="BackgroundAnimation" Background="#FF448DCA" />
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" >
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter
                              x:Name="contentPresenter"
                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Margin="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Button CornerBehaviorTest:Corner.Radii="10,5,5,5" Content="Button" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,22,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### Old answer

You have several options:

- Create the various radii types you want using application resources and use StaticResource Binding (Expression Blend just lets you do this in the GUI which is nice, but you can do it manually)
- You can create an attached behaviour and have a single Radius property that sets all 4 corners.
- Create an attached dependency property (bind the template to a new Radius property)
- You can create a custom control as you suggest.

Comment: I think the first option is what I've got at the moment.  The second I'm not too sure about how to proceed, and the third: what is the difference between a user control and a custom control in this context?

Comment: @descf: Typo fixed. I meant Custom control. You need to investigate Silverlight behaviours. They are nice parasitic bits of code that can add new behaviour to any type. Try this link: http://openlightgroup.net/Blog/tabid/58/EntryId/17/Creating-a-simple-Silverlight-3-Behavior.aspx

Comment: @descf: The more I think about this the more I think you might want to template bind the corners to an attached property instead.

Comment: @descf: full (tested) sourcecode supplied for the appropriate property.

Comment: I've gone down a different route but I'll give you the mark for this anyrate.  I created a class library project with a Themes folder containing a file generic.xaml  - the content being, for example, the xaml you have posted above with any references to CornerRadius set to TemplateBinding.  I added an empty class and set it to inherit from Button, added a dependency property of type CornerRadius, added this to the constructer: DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ButtonControl); and this as an attribute on the class: [TemplatePart(Name = "CornerRadius", Type = typeof(CornerRadius))]  That's it, it works.